How can I track transactions on a given pool's Raydium?
My project requires tracking transactions of a given pool on Raydium. (Solana Network).
Specifically, fields such as token broadcasts, timestamp, type (purchase, sale) are needed
I tried through Connection.onLogs, but as I understand it, it tracks everything over the network, and for me it either works immediately, or is tracked with a delay of 20 minutes, sometimes an hour
I will be grateful for any information
